# It was not possible to complete the request due to file system permission restrictions when ckeditor access azure blob

Tags: typescript, asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor, single-page-application, azure-blob-storage

I am working on the application which is using Ckeditor for the process. now its using local file system which is deployed in same server. our client would like to migrate this to cloud. since Ckeditor supports azure blob storage. i have changed the backend connector, but sill not able to connect to storage account.
when i browse url "It was not possible to complete the request due to file system permission restrictions"[Error-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJX44.png)

Comment: Are the permissions configured for this access? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources?tabs=dotnet

Comment: @Azeem, thanks for your response!!. i have granted all required permissions and checked. i have tried with anonymous permission as well.

Comment: Right. Can you please add the configuration in the question as well? Did you try to test your blob access using a script or something else?

Comment: Here's a relevant article that you can use to test with JavaScript: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser

Comment: i have a firewall setting enabled. its blocking me...if i open firewall,application could access it. client is not ready to compromise any change in firewall. can we pass SAS toaken in CKFInder and access?

Comment: Can't you just add a rule to the firewall instead of disabling it?